# Numeric null value vs value--comparison

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to compare 2 values -1 is null and other is numeric, but it somehow equals to "equal"

```
declare @value1 int;
declare @value2 int;
select @value1 = null
select @value2 = 1
if (@value1 <> @value2)
    print 'not equal'
else 
    print 'equal'
```

Result: Equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` fails all comparisons  therefore `if(null <> @value)` is false.

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot compare `NULL` values, neither with `=` nor `<>` since `NULL` means undefined.

Use `IS` if you want to know if a values *is* `NULL`, you can use:

```
IF ( ( @value1 IS NULL 
       AND @value2 IS NULL ) 
      OR (( @value1 IS NOT NULL 
            AND @value2 IS NOT NULL 
            AND @value1 = @value2 )) ) 
  PRINT 'equal' 
ELSE 
  PRINT 'not equal'
```

See: [What if null if null is null null null is null?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/09/30/what-if-null-if-null-is-null-null-null-is-null.aspx)